# Redirecting to specific page depending upon Authentication and Authorization

Tags: spring-security, ldap

I am building an Application where I am authorizing the user based on his Role. Role is defined in Ldap. We have three roles finance, cloud and sales. Depending upon the role we want to redirect to the particular page on successful login. If login fails it should redirect to some error page.

I have written the following in spring-security.xml. I am not able to redirecting to different pages .

```
 <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.3.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/finance*" access="ROLE_FINANCE"  />

        <logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/cloud*" access="ROLE_CLOUD" />


        <logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/sales*" access="ROLE_SALES" />

        <!-- <form-login login-page="/login1" default-target-url="/login1"
            authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" /> -->
        <logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
        <!-- <form-login login-page="/login.vtu" authentication-success-handler-ref="customHandler"
            authentication-failure-url="/login.vtu?error=true" default-target-url="/login.vtu"
            login-processing-url="/j_security_check"  />  -->
    </http>
 <authentication-manager>
         <ldap-authentication-provider 
           user-search-filter="(uid={0})"
           user-search-base="cn=worldAdmin"
           group-search-filter="(uniqueMember={0})"
           group-search-base="cn=worldAdmin"
           group-role-attribute="cn"
           role-prefix="ROLE_">
         </ldap-authentication-provider>
 </authentication-manager>

 <ldap-server url="ldap://localhost:12389/o=xyz" manager-dn="cn=xyzAdmin,cn=worldAdmin,o=xyz" manager-password="abc" /> 

</beans:beans>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use authentication-success-handler-ref to redirect to the particular page based on User Role. *(As per Spring Security, authentication-success-handler-ref Should not be used in combination with default-target-url (or always-use-default-target-url) as the 
  implementation should always deal with navigation to the subsequent destination)*
- Use authentication-failure-url to redirect when login fails:

```
    <form-login login-page="/login.vtu" authentication-success-handler-ref="customHandler"
            authentication-failure-url="/login.vtu?error=true" />

     <bean id="customHandler" class="x.y.z.web.handler.CustomHandler " />
```

```
    public class CustomHandler extends SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler {
       @Override
       public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
              //authentication.getAuthorities() to check role
              if(isFinancialRole){
                  response.sendRedirect(getFinancialRedirectUrl());
              }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I followed this procedure but I am getting authentication.getAuthorities as a empty collection..

Comment: This means your LdapAuthenticationProvider is not setting up roles (Authorities). I believe 'group-role-attribute' attribute is not set up correctly.

Comment: thanks for the reply ..now i am able to get the roles but it gives me all the directories from ldap but i want only the particular directory under which the current user is ..

Comment: Please try some other values for group-search-base attribute. 'group-search-base' defines base DN under which LDAP integration should look for match.

Answer (score 0):

login.xhtml

```
<h:head >
    <f:metadata>
      <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{loginBean.onPageLoad}"/>
  </f:metadata>
</h:head>
```

loginBean

```
public void onPageLoad(){
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if (!(auth instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)) {
        try {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(url);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```